# How to enclose HTML in a ternary operator condition as you would with a normal if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, ternary-operator

When I'm using the IF Statement, I normally do something like this:

```
    <?php 
    if ($var ===0){ ?>
    <section>We broke out of PHP</section>
    <?php ////// we are back in PHP 
    } else {

        }       
 ?>
```

How can I archive the same thing with a ternary operator, something like:

```
  <?php 
    $var ===0?: $_breakHere?>
    <section>We broke out of PHP</section>
    <?php ////// we are back in PHP 
    $_ContinueHere
    } else {

        }       
 ?>
```

I'd put all the html block into a PHP variable, but I want to break our of PHP and back into it, for syntax reading purposes.

Comment: Have you considered not using a ternary operator; or if your goal is to put text into a variable, using a heredoc? Also note that you can always put the two text options into separate variables, and then use a `$c = $cond ? $a : $b` with the variables you defined.

Comment: I'd try to make the code more readable, not less.

Comment: hate that syntax, jumping in and out of php is not a great approach

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically, the expression with the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), is a **single** instruction, and you cannot break a single instruction across PHP tags, regardless of nesting PHP and HTML code blocks.

For example, the followings generate syntax errors:

```
<?php echo 1==2 ? "eq" : ?><?php "ne"; ?> // syntax error, unexpected '?>'
<?php $seven = ?><?php 7; ?>              // syntax error, unexpected '?>'
```